# How to sync variables like score in Unity Photon?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

When each character eats an item, their score goes up. ex) MasterScore, CustomerScore
I find on the internet and use OnPhononSerializeview

```
public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {
            stream.SendNext(MasterScore);
            stream.SendNext(CustomerScore);
        }
        else
        {
            MasterScore = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();
            CustomerScore = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();
        }
    }
```

When MasterScore goes up, the score goes up on both master and geust's clients.
but CustomerScore goes up, the score doesn't go up on master client.
furthermore, Suddenly clientscore goes to 0.

```
public class synchronization : MonoBehaviourPun, IPunObservable
```

I declared IPunObservable of course, and add Photon View script on gameobject.
I think there is a problem with the synchronization process.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might want to look into [Custom Player Properties](https://doc.photonengine.com/pun/current/gameplay/synchronization-and-state#custom_properties)